# Objective-C Xamarin Binding not working on device

Tags: ios, build, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Hello Guys I'm trying to make a Binding for our Objective-C SDK, I follow the steps in the Xamarin walkthrough it works on simulator but not on device, what could be the problem knowing that I'm using Xcode 6.4, I also use a Fat library (one that contains the builds for i386 and armv7 architectures).
I've tried cleaning and rebuilding the project, and also added the -v-v-v as additional builds parameters but nothing!!! All i'm getting is this error message :

**Failed to load Aot Module**

Comment: Google can't index screenshots.  Please take the time to post relevant error messages in the body of the question.

Answer (score 0):

On Xamarin forums they say that it gonna work if you just clean the solution. So if it doesn't help, try removing all the "bin" and "obj" folders in all the projects and build again. If even that doesn't work you should probably consider it as a bug and write to their support.